# How to set multiple targets to ProxyFactoryBean and invoke one of the target method based on Config?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, java-8

In java I want to implement proxy class (proxy Factory Bean) which will take multiple targets(implementing same interface) and invoke one of the target method based configuration value.

Dog & Cat implementing Animal and based on some configuration value(Y or N) want to invoke one of its implementations. This can be done using strategy but my problem is that similar logic need to applied for other implementations which are implementing different interfaces.(Example below I added below Audi and Benz classes implementing Car Interface) and want to choose of the implementations based on the configuration.

```
  public interface Animal
        {

          public void sound();

        }

        public class Dog implements Animal
        {

          public void sound()
          {

            System.out.print("bark");
          }
        }

        public class Cat implements Animal
        {

          public void sound()
          {

            System.out.print("Meow");
          }
        }
```

2nd bean:

```
public interface Car
  {

    public void make();

  }

  public class Audi implements Car
  {

    public void make()
    {

      System.out.print("Audi");
    }
  }

  public class Benz implements Car
  {

    public void make()
    {

      System.out.print("Mercedes");
    }
  }
```

example spring configuration

```
<bean id "animalService" class="proxyFactoryBean">
<list>
<target id"Y". "class"="com.Dog">
<target id"N". "class"="com.Cat">
<list>
</bean>

<bean id "carService" class="proxyFactoryBean">
<list>
<target id"Y". "class"="com.Audi">
<target id"N". "class"="com.Benz">
<list>
</bean>
```

and In controller inject same interface(Car,Animal) and call original method with out any proxy injection.

Can someone please suggest how it can be done with  either SpringProxyFactoryBean or custom implementation?

Basically in the proxy class, I want to check the configuration value and depending on that I want to invoke method on that particular implementation object.

If config value is Y , from the list of targets defined, get Y bean reference in the proxy and invoke method on it.

Answer (score 0):

Proxies are usually used when you want to intercept the request to a method call (preferably an interface method) before the target implementation is invoked.

Spring allows this with the help of ProxyFactoryBean. You configure it to proxy one or more interfaces **(different kinds)** and a target implementation and one or more interceptors. When you ask for an implementation of any of these interfaces, configured interceptors get a chance to sniff but eventually the invoked method on target class is called.

Not too sure what your eventual goal is but all you are trying to do is to create an indirection and based on some condition either invoke class A implementation or Class B implementation. ProxyFactoryBean doesn't address this directly.

One of the options is to create multiple Spring managed beans for ProxyFactoryBean, one each of each implementation and get the bean from factory by name. Their id names will obviously be different.

Second option is for you to create a third class implementing the interface, assign that class as target in the Spring configuration and based on your condition either call Class A implementation of Class B implementation. Have a look at an example code snippet.

```
class CarDecider implements Car{
/*  
either get Audi impl from BeanFactory or ApplicationContext 
if they are configured beans
or create a new instance in case you don't have access to 
BeanFactory and serving through singleton instance is not a 
requirement
*/
    public void make(){
      if(<your condition for Audi true>){  
        beanFactory.getBean(Audi.class).make(); 
        // OR
        new Audi().make();
      }else{
        beanFactory.getBean(Benz.class).make(); 
        // OR
        new Benz().make();
      }
    }
}
```

Third option will be you avoid using ProxyFactoryBean completely. Register both implementations for an interface by different names and ask for them based on condition from BeanFactory.

Comment: Thank you, If I go with 2nd option(Decider), I need to write decider classes for all services implementing different interfaces, Across application, for each service interface (there are two implementations) and select one of them depending on global configuration.Ex.- if brand is amazon, choose amazon implementations or if brand is shopify choose shopify implementations. This applicable for all services across application. I just want to write one single proxy kind of bean, which will check for global config value(Amazon/Shopify) and select one implementation from two configured in the list.

Comment: In that case you really need to think if ProxyFactoryBean is the right option for you. See the third option provided in the answer